# Foundation 5 Icons not working in production, rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am using the foundation 5 icons in my rails app, I have the gem installed and the icon files in my assets/fonts.  The icons are working fine when I am running my app on local host but the icons are not working in production.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a `rake assets:precompile`? That would be my guess is that the precompiled version has not been created and put into public.

Comment: Would I want to do this before or after I push to production.  I am using heroku.